# example of p-group with infinite Frattini subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups, infinite-groups

> Is there an infinite $p$-group $G$ with infinite Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G)\not = G$?

In "[Subgroups of Teichmuller Modular Groups](https://books.google.com/books?id=KPoEtBwBEA0C&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=infinite+frattini+subgroup&source=bl&ots=ySrvnxJe2F&sig=a6K-mBlbxZiIPfcuE-RXMpgV2UY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBTgKahUKEwj7uamzlvnHAhXKshQKHdQqAao#v=onepage&q=infinite%20frattini%20subgroup&f=false)" there is an example but I don't get it because I don't know much about manifolds. I hope someone can come up with an easier example.

Comment: How about a direct product of infinitely many copies of a cyclic group of order $p^2$? All elements of order $p$ lie in the Frattini subgroup.

Comment: It is very good example but I prefer a example without direct product some finitely presented group will be perfect if such group existed.

Comment: It's an open problem whether there exists a finitely presented infinite torsion group, so you are unlikely to find a finitely presented example! The Grigorchuk group is a finitely generated infinite $2$-group with Frattini subgroup of index $8$, so that is an example, but these are nontrivial matters!